# Hive - remove " " quotes in DDL Table creation

Tags: regex, hive, ddl

I've a CSV with 400 columns and some of them have " " in the values. For examples:

```
Field_A
"123"
""
"21111"
```

My question is: is possible when I'm creating the table in Hive to remove automatically this quotes from the data? Or I need to put `regexp_replace()` in every fields to remove that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the below post from hortonworks answers your question.
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/66603/how-to-remove-double-quote-from-csv-file-at-time-o.html

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
)
```